# How to Find All Defaultly Installed Packages on Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: 16.04, package-management, xubuntu, default-programs

Is there any way I can find all the default installed packages for a given Ubuntu version, like Xubuntu 16.04.3 x86? I'm not talking about the list of the packages currently installed on the system but the packages which you'll find installed after a clean install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the .manifest

http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/

You will see a "ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.manifest"

Click the link - http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.manifest

From any web browser you can search packages and use it any way you wish ;)

You can download it as a text file if you prefer.

Rinse and repeat for other versions

http://mirror.us.leaseweb.net/ubuntu-cdimage/xubuntu/releases/16.04/release/

get xubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.manifest

http://mirror.us.leaseweb.net/ubuntu-cdimage/xubuntu/releases/16.04/release/xubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.manifest

or

http://mirror.us.leaseweb.net/ubuntu-cdimage/xubuntu/releases/16.04/release/xubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-i386.manifest

Comment: OP asked for Xubuntu default packages...

Comment: Umm ... Read the xubuntu manifest

Comment: Great! Now it's fine.